# ubuntu on virtual machine vs ubuntu install, what the difference?

Tags: zend-framework, ubuntu, virtualization, virtual-machine

I have windows xp in my work and i programming on zend framework.
I need to install ubuntu for execute doctrine orm commands from linux console, I faile to do it on windows.
I thinking about 2 option of UBUNTU installation:
1.install ubuntu 10.04 on Virtual Box (Sun Virtual Machine).
2.create new primary partition and install ubuntu 10.04  directly.

Which options do you suggest to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If it's something you won't be using much, just stick it in a Virtual Machine. 
It's slower because it's running inside another system, so you'll have the windows stuff running as well as the ubuntu stuff, but if you're not going to be using it all the time, then not installing it as a stand alone means you don't mess with your MBR, and it's easier to get rid of when you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It's more easy, quickly, and safe if you use a VM, so you don't have to mess with the disk partition and so on.